# Place a border or line inside the margin of a span in a grid system/bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, border

You all know the 960/940px grid systems. I have to do a layout with borders between some span elements, i.e.

```
[margin | span2] [mar... + border + ...gin][span2]
```

I mean, the border / splitting line should be in the middle of two spans, but *inside* the spacing margin.

It should be a solution without images, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this idea look for starters?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/8FEap/

You apply the class .borderLeft to a span if you want a border to its left

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6">span6</div>
<div class="span3 borderLeft">span3</div>
<div class="span3 borderLeft">span3</div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

and use this CSS

```
.borderLeft { 

/* use border-box so border is applied inside the span and doesn't break the grid */

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

/* define your border */
border-left: 2px solid red;

/* remove the default bootstrap padding */
margin-left:10px !important;


/* make final adjustments to restore padding to span */
padding-left:10px;
margin-right:10px !important;

}
```